# TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, machine-learning

Estou tentando aplicar o algoritimo do NMF num csv e depois extrair as frases ligadas a cada topico

```
import pandas
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.decomposition import NMF

def display_topics(model, feature_names, no_top_words):
    for topic_idx, topic in enumerate(model.components_):
        print "Topic %d:" % (topic_idx)
        print " ".join([feature_names[i]
                    for i in topic.argsort()[:-no_top_words - 1:-1]])

textos = pandas.read_csv('teste_nmf.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')
textos_limpos = textos['frase_limpa']
textos_bruts = textos['frase_brut']
textos_bruts_list = textos_bruts.values.tolist()
textos_limpos_list = textos_limpos.values.tolist()

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(textos_limpos_list)
tfidf_feature_names = tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()


#n_components: numero de topicos
nmf = NMF(n_components = 2, random_state = 1, alpha = .1, l1_ratio = .5, init = 'nndsvd').fit(tfidf)


#Numero de palavras por topico
no_top_words = 2

#Visualizaçao dos topicos com as palavras
print 'NMF'
topics = display_topics(nmf, tfidf_feature_names, no_top_words)
print topics

#extrair frases ligadas aos topicos
for topic in range(len(topics)): #TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
    print "Topic {}:".format(topic)
    docs = np.argsort(document_topics[:, topic])[::-1]
    for text in docs[:3]:
        text_brut = " ".join(textos_bruts_list[text].split(",")[:2])
        print " ".join(textos_limpos_list[text].split(",")[:2]) + ',' + text_brut
```

**Um exemplo (tosco) de dataset:**

```
frase_limpa,frase_brut
manga fruta gostosa,a manga é uma fruta gostosa  
computador objeto importante,o computador é um objeto importante
banana fruto popular,a banana é um fruto popular
lapis coisa importante,o lapis é uma coisa importante
uva roxa,a uva é roxa
telefone objeto mundial,o telefone é um objeto mundial
```

**Meu resultado:**

> NMF
>
> Topic 0:
>
> importante objeto
>
> Topic 1:
>
> uva roxa
>
> None
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "teste_NMF.py", line 55, in 
>       for topic in range(len(topics)): #TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
>
> TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

**O que eu esperava mais ou menos:**

> Topic 0:
>
> importante objeto
>
> Topic 1:
>
> uva roxa
>
> Topic 0:
>
> computador objeto importante,o computador é um objeto importante
>
> telefone objeto mundial,o telefone é um objeto mundial
>
> lapis coisa importante,o lapis é uma coisa importante
>
> Topic 1:
>
> uva roxa,a uva é roxa

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que a função `display_topics` não possui uma cláusula `return` nem `yield`, logo ela sempre vai retornar `None` todas as vezes.

```
topics = display_topics(nmf, tfidf_feature_names, no_top_words)
```

Significa que a variável `topics` é `None` pois é isso que a `display_topics()` retorna.

```
for topic in range(len(topics)):
```

Tenta calcular o `len()` de `topics` que é `None` por isso você tem o erro.

Comment: Mas como eu poderia resolver isso?

Comment: @marin Isso depende da sua lógica... Por exemplo, retornar alguma coisa em `display_topics` - se você coloca um `return []` ao final, ela retornará uma lista vazia, e assim não dará erro, pois `len([])` é `0`. Eu não entendo direito o que você está escrevendo: Criou uma função com o prefixo `display_` que significa *"exibir"*, semanticamente ela deveria exibir os tópicos e finalizar, porém você está tentando pegar o retorno dela em uma outra parte do código!! Será que ela deveria se chamar `format_topics`? Ou você deve pegar o que precisa de outro lugar? Ou converter em 2 funções separadas?

Comment: @marin Resumindo, você tem que saber o que quer fazer com essa parte do código, para arrumá-lo. Porém a sua pergunta está respondida.

Answer (score 2):

Sua função `display_topics()` não possui um `return`. Você precisa acrescentar um `return` a ela com a lista a ser retornada.

Answer (score -1):

Como já foi dito, falta um `return` em `display_topics`.
Seu erro é bem comum, pois esperava que as mudanças em `display_topics` tivessem efeito fora da função, isso se chama [escopo](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjK-oTDiKXsAhVEEbkGHcocAjsQFjAAegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpt.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FEscopo_(computa%25C3%25A7%25C3%25A3o)&usg=AOvVaw2K3f29Oxje5b2h_RAqMoOW).